# How to extract specific data from axios call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, axios

I want to display in the UI only one single record, which is the most recently generated one (that has the highest ID value). Right now I have all the JSON data displayed in the UI but I want to limit that to a single extract.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WBGf.png)

```
function PriorityProgressTrim({asms_number}) {
    const [checkForRecords, setCheckForRecords] = useState(true);
    const [pprecords, setPprecords] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(asms_number)
      // axios(`https://besterdev-api.apps.pcfepg3mi.gm.com/api/v1/pprecords/latest/${asms_number}`).then((response) => {
        axios(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pprecords/latest/${asms_number}`).then((response) => {
          console.log (response.data)
          setPprecords(response.data); setError(null); }).catch(setError);}, [checkForRecords]);

      if (error) return <p>An error occurred</p>

        return (

        <div> 
          {pprecords.map(({id, date, pprecord, asmsNumber}) => (
            <Box component="form" sx={{ '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 0.5, width: '80ch' }, }}>
              <div>
              <TextField error className='Font' fullWidth id="outlined-multiline-static" size="small" variant="outlined" label={date} multiline rows={5} value={pprecord} />
              </div>
            </Box>)).reverse()}
            
        </div>);}
            
    
    export default PriorityProgressTrim;
```

Comment: Is it JSON or an Object? JSON is a string; an object is not? Regardless, please include that in your post. Then show your attempts and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: You're currently creating a Box for each record. Instead you just find the one with the highest `id` and only display a Box for that record...what part of this are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you receive a string, you need first to parse to a JSON object:

`let data = JSON.parse(response.data);`

Then you can sort the elements inside the resulted JSON array, and extract the last one (that with the highest ID):

```
let lastRecord = data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id).pop();
setPprecord(lastRecord);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
function PriorityProgressTrim({asms_number}) {
    const [checkForRecords, setCheckForRecords] = useState(true);
    const [pprecord, setPprecord] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(asms_number)
      // axios(`https://besterdev-api.apps.pcfepg3mi.gm.com/api/v1/pprecords/latest/${asms_number}`).then((response) => {
        axios(`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pprecords/latest/${asms_number}`).then((response) => {
          console.log (response.data)
          let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
          let lastRecord = data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id).pop();
          setPprecord(lastRecord); setError(null); }).catch(setError);}, [checkForRecords]);

      if (error) return <p>An error occurred</p>

        return (

        <div> 
            <Box component="form" sx={{ '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 0.5, width: '80ch' }, }}>
              <div>
              <TextField error className='Font' fullWidth id="outlined-multiline-static" size="small" variant="outlined" label={date} multiline rows={5} value={pprecord} />
              </div>
            </Box>
            
        </div>);}
            
    
    export default PriorityProgressTrim;
```